# How to write a function of type `[(a,b)] -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [(a,b)]`

Tags: haskell

I have an association list

```
L :: [(a,b)]
```

where every `a` is associated to a `b`.

The `b` is just extra information, and the interesting part is `a`.

I want to work with `a`, so I have a function `f` of type `[a] -> [a]`. (In my problem I actually have `[a] -> [[a]]`, so if your answer would generalize to any container that I can traverse that would be good.

I think I need something like

```
[(a,b)] -> ([a] -> T a) -> T (a,b)
```

where `T` is some kind of container I can traverse). This function basically rearranges the `a`'s around, it doesn't create new ones, or delete anything.

I seem to have gotten stuck on what's the most idiomatic way to run `f` on the `a` part of `[(a,b)]`, and at the end attach back the `b`.

I thought of using `Data.Map` to simply do a lookup at the end, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do what I'm after, somehow "thread along" the `b` along with the rest of computation.

If there isn't, could you explain why?

The obvious other way is to rewrite `f` but I don't want that since `f` doesn't care about `b`.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: So the function of type `[a] -> [a]` doesn't change the length of the list?

Comment: No, all I do is re-arrange the elements

Comment: So, you basically want an `unzip`, function application and then `zip` it sounds like.

Comment: @rafalio Would it be possible to provide a function of type `a -> Int` that gives the new index of the element `a` instead?

Comment: If you really have a generic function with of type `[a]->[[a]]` just feed it your original list. Otherwise it's impossible.

Comment: *"what's the most idiomatic way to run `f` on the `a` part of `[(a,b)]`, and at the end attach back the `b`."* then it should've been `:: [(a,b)] -> (a -> a) -> [(a,b)]`. `[a]->[a]` can have all kinds of semantics, coalescing, splitting, permuting (what you seem to imply), etc...

Comment: My bad for miscommunication, I do not have a general function, the function is concrete for a specific `a`.

Comment: and what does it do? Permutes the list? Can it turn `[1..5]` into  `[1,1,2,2,2]`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, an example will help.  [(1,1), (2,2)] as [(a,b)] and reverse as ([a] -> [a]) gives [(2,1), (1,2)] or [(2,2), (1,1)]?

Comment: Did you try arrows, `first` in particular?

Comment: What about using `unzip` first and then `zip`ping later, after applying your function to the first part? Something like: `let (m, n) = unzip l in zip (f m) n` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type `b` being "just extra information" reminds me of the [`Env`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Env.html#g:2) comonad, which is one of the simplest comonads and can be used to attach useful extra information to values.

```
import Control.Comonad
import Control.Comonad.Env

toenv :: [(a,b)] -> [Env b a]
toenv = map (\(a,b)->env b a)
```

Perhaps you could rewrite your function of type `[a] -> [a]` to work with the more general type `Comonad w => [w a] -> [w a]`, polymorphic in the comonad. If you had to generate new values, that would be a problem (comonads don't offer a general way of putting values inside a comonadic context) but since you only want to reorder existing values (or drop them) it would work ok.

Remember that you can always can get the `a` value from an `w a` using the [`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v%3aextract) function.

To recover the original `[a] -> [a]` function from the generalized one, just use the [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad-Identity.html) comonad.

```
import Control.Comonad.Identity

simplify :: Functor f => (forall w. Comonad w => f (w a) -> f (w a)) -> f a -> f a
simplify f = fmap extract . f . fmap Identity
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a

```
rearrange :: [a] -> [a]
```

but you want to rearrange a list like [(a,b)].

you have just to rewrite rearrange as

```
rearrangeBy :: (c -> a) -> [c] -> [c]
```

substituting occurrences of element x with (f x) on check positions

Then rewrite your target function passing the new one

```
targetfun :: ((c -> a) -> [c] -> [c]) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
targetfun rearrangeBy pairList = rearrangeBy fst pairList
```

Answer (score 1):

That function can be implemented like this:

1. extract key list from that association list
2. apply that "rearrange" function to this key list to get a new key list (maybe embedded in a container)
3. map each key in that new key list to its corresponding pair in the original association list

The above description can be translated to Haskell code directly:

```
generalArrange :: (Functor f, Eq a, Show a) => [(a, b)] -> ([a] -> f a) -> f (a, b)
generalArrange al f = fmap keyToPair $ f as
    where as = map fst al
          keyToPair k = lookup k al
          lookup k [] = error $ "Invalid key: " ++ show k
          lookup k (a:as)
            | k == fst a = a
            | otherwise = lookup k as
```

---

Testing:

```
ghc > let al = [(2, "def"), (1, "abc"), (3, "ijk")]
ghc > generalArrange al sort
[(1,"abc"),(2,"def"),(3,"ijk")]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "thread along" a value of another type in a `[a] -> T a` function.  And once that has been applied, you're going to need some way of looking up the corresponding `b` for each `a`.  I think your idea of a `Map` is about the best you can do without rewriting `f`.  Dependent on `a`, a `HashMap` or `IntMap` might work better in your specific case.